# Removing last character from each element in Python list

Tags: python, arrays, element

I have a list find_words which is

```
[u'Duration$', u'Noun$', u'Adjective$']
```

I would like to remove all the '$' so it looks like

```
[u'Duration', u'Noun', u'Adjective']
```

How do I go about this? Also, how do I re-add the '$' as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this simply with a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY&list=UUAuqj5Bs5mTTl1mIVDmuAlw&index=1&feature=plcp) and [`str.rstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

```
[word.rstrip("$") for word in words]
```

Or to add them:

```
[word+"$" for word in words]
```

E.g:

```
>>> words = ['Duration$', 'Noun$', 'Adjective$']
>>> words = [word.rstrip("$") for word in words]
>>> words
['Duration', 'Noun', 'Adjective']
>>> [word+"$" for word in words]
['Duration$', 'Noun$', 'Adjective$']
```

Comment: Do I have to import rstrip? I keep getting. ''Word' object has no attribute 'rstrip'' using word.rstrip("$") for word in words

Comment: @ono3 That would imply that your words are not actually strings, but ``Word`` objects, and hence do not have an ``rstrip()`` method. Check the contents of your list.

Comment: If they are objects, can I still remove the '$' somehow?

Comment: @ono3 I would presume there would be a way, but it entirely depends on how the object works.

Comment: I used the def __unicode__ function in the models. It worked after that.

Answer (score 3):

List comprehension is your friend.

You have a choice to remove just the last character `word[:-1]` or a $ if it's present `word.rstrip('$')`.  This is going to be application defined

```
 words = [u'Duration$', u'Noun$', u'Adjective$']
 result = [word[:-1] for word in words]
```

Also to re-add it:

```
 added_back = [word + '$' for word in result]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
words = [ x[:-1] for x in words ]
```

will remove last character from each item

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last character, regardless of what it is:

```
find_words = [i[:-1] for i in find_words]
```

But you should be using `rstrip` if it's guaranteed to be a `$`:

```
find_words = [i.rstrip("$") for i in words]
```

To add a `$`:

```
find_words = [i + "$" for i in find_words]
```